# Working with several asynchronous requests

Tags: javascript

Suppose my app needs to do several asynchronous requests, but I want to work with the data only once all requests are complete.

What is the simplest way to achieve this in vanilla JS or jquery?
Sample of code appreciate thanks

Comment: do you stuff in the result listener. I did same thing in actionscript.

Comment: @Jaan: He wants to do stuff once multiple requests finished.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery's promise system allows you to do this easily:

```
$.when(req1, req2, req3).done(function(res1, res2, res3) {
    // all requests finished successfully
});
```

The `reqN` variables need to be promise objects, such as the ones returned by `$.ajax()`.

If you have an array of them instead of separate variables, you can use this instead:

```
$.when.apply($, reqs).done(...);
```

Related documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/